# The Zune software doesn't remove heard podcasts anymore, why?

Tags: zune-software, zune-hd

I've recently purchased a new PC and moved my Zune library to it. The PC has Windows 10 Professional on it. I installed the Zune software on it and as I said I moved my library over to it. It seems to be working, with the exception that for some reason every podcast I listen to is never automatically removed when I sync my Zune HD to it. I've double checked the settings and I believe everything is all right, but I could be wrong about that. What could be causing this problem and how do I resolve it?

Comment: [This might be a better place for your question](http://forums.windowscentral.com/zune/)

Comment: I didn't even know that Windows CEntral had a forum for the Zune player and software, Thanks.